# Webpack ProvidePlugin and Global variables

Tags: webpack, momentjs

I'm extremely new to webpack and one of the first things I've noticed is that I can wrap jquery in the following so its available globally to my javascript, which is lovely. I want to do this with other frameworks that I use like moment, accounting, and any plugins I need to use, i.e. jQuery UI for instance.

Being naive and having not read up on webpack properly, I simply tried the below, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/config.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js'),
        filename: 'main.build.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            accounting: 'accounting',
            moment: 'moment'
            // jQuery: './src/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
            // jqueryui : './src/vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min',
            // listjs: './src/vendor/list.js/dist/list.min',
            // moment: './src/vendor/moment/min/moment.min',
            // nouislider: './src/vendor/nouislider/distribute/nouislider.min',
            // accounting: './src/js/plugins/accounting',
            // imagesLoaded: './src/vendor/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min',
            // parsley: './src/vendor/parsleyjs/dist/parsley.min',
            // urlQuery: './src/vendor/domurl/url.min'
        }),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\.\/locale$/, 'empty-module', false, /js$/)
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: [ "babel-preset-es2015" ].map(require.resolve)
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    stats: {
        colors: true
    },
    devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

This is my total arrogance, but really hoping someone can help as it would be really nice to have this stuff available globally and not have to import it into certain files, I'm trying to convert the entire front end js stack to es6 modules.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: After installing moment via NPM this actually works now, but in browser I get 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'moment' of undefined' - would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of fiddling around this did actually work fine. As soon as moment was installed via npm, this was great.

Comment: Important to note that you need to have it installed via npm (it should reside in your `node_modules`) and to have the proper case `moment: 'moment'`